# JavaPoet Generic Parameter

Tags: java, code-generation, annotation-processing, javapoet

How would I generate a method with the following signature?

```
public static <T extends MyClass & MyInterface> MyOtherClass someMethod(T type)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a [`TypeVariableName`](https://github.com/square/javapoet/blob/master/src/main/java/com/squareup/javapoet/TypeVariableName.java) along with [`addTypeVariable`](https://github.com/square/javapoet/blob/master/src/main/java/com/squareup/javapoet/MethodSpec.java#L343) might help here -

```
import com.squareup.javapoet.*;
import javax.lang.model.element.Modifier;
import java.io.IOException;

public class AttemptGeneric {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    ClassName myClass = ClassName.get("com", "MyClass");
    ClassName myOtherClass = ClassName.get("com", "MyOtherClass");
    ClassName myInterface = ClassName.get("com", "MyInterface");
    TypeVariableName typeVariableName = TypeVariableName.get("T", myClass);

    MethodSpec methodSpec = MethodSpec.methodBuilder("someMethod")
            .returns(myOtherClass)
            .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC, Modifier.STATIC)
            .addTypeVariable(typeVariableName.withBounds(myInterface))
            .addParameter(typeVariableName,"type")
            .build();


    TypeSpec genericClass = TypeSpec.classBuilder("GenericImpl")
            .addModifiers(Modifier.PUBLIC, Modifier.FINAL)
            .addMethod(methodSpec)
            .build();

    JavaFile javaFile = JavaFile.builder("com", genericClass)
            .build();

    javaFile.writeTo(System.out);

  }
}
```

***Note*** - I've my `MyClass`, `MyOtherClass` and `MyInterface` all within a package named `com` which is where the class implementing this `main()` also resides.

Imports used -

---

Generates output as --

> ```
> package com;
>
> public final class GenericImpl {
>   public static <T extends MyClass & MyInterface> MyOtherClass someMethod(T type) {
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: A bit late but thanks, here is the link to issue https://github.com/square/javapoet/issues/543

Comment: @Pedram - wc. you were too quick to post it as an issue I believe. :)

Comment: yup, I have deadlines to meet ;)